# How do I transform a pandas DataFrame into a count table?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with columns I'll call A, B, C, D, etc. The only columns I care about are A and B. I want to get another DataFrame where the columns are the unique values in A and the rows are the unique values in B, and each cell contains the number of lines in the original DataFrame that contained that pair of A and B values. I can probably do this by just iterating through the rows and counting, then constructing the new table of counts, but I feel like there's a more efficient way to do it with pandas functions (groupby? pivot?) but I'm having trouble figuring out the exact recipe.

As an example:

```
index  A  B  C  D
    0  m  x  2  3
    1  m  x  0  1
    2  n  x  1  1
    3  m  y  5  9
    4  n  z  0  0
```

And I would produce this table:

```
   m  n
x  2  1
y  1  0
z  0  1
```

I hope that example is clear enough.

Comment: What about `pd.crosstab`. Try `pd.crosstab(index=df.B,columns=df.A)`

Comment: Crosstab is exactly what I needed. If you post it as answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":list("mmnmn"), "B":list("xxxyz"), 
                   "C":[2,0,1,5,0],"D":[3,1,1,9,0]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame([{v:0 
                     for v in set(df["A"])} 
                     for _ in sorted(set(df["B"]))], 
                   index=sorted(set(df["B"])))

for i,j in zip(df["A"],df["B"]):
    df2[i][j] += 1

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   n  m
x  1  2
y  0  1
z  1  0
```

but there is porbably a more elegant way.